# How to store and mark all mouse-clicked-point on an Image loaded in JPanel?

Tags: java, event-handling, jframe, jpanel, mouseevent

Up till now I have used the code given below to load image in a new new JFrame and coordinates of pixels of image are hard-coded in the code itself. However, I wish to do it dynamically i.e mark points clicked by mouse and store all the coordinates in an array or so.

The code is running properly, Image is chosen using JFileChooser in another class and the path is passed as a parameter to this class.

Please help me out.

```
   public class GraphicsSet extends JFrame{

 Font f ;

 BufferedImage baseImage ;

File file ;

String Gimage;

JFrame imageFrame;

public GraphicsSet(String Image)
{
    super("Frame") ;
   // imageFrame = new JFrame("Click on to select points");
    file = new File(Image) ;
    Gimage = Image;
    try
    {
        baseImage = ImageIO.read(file) ;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e) ; 
    }
    int imageWidth = baseImage.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = baseImage.getHeight();
    System.out.println(imageWidth);

    setBounds(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight) ;
    setVisible(true) ;
    //setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(baseImage, 0, 0, null) ;

    String[] coordsText = new String[]{ 
      "264.33,329.94","244.24,382.57","243.00,328.88",
      "264.33,329.94","272.06,331.59","278.30,341.00",
      "284.28,350.02","282.18,367.78","275.24,375.79",
      "272.89,378.50","269.26,380.27","266.00,381.66",
      "259.36,384.50","258.52,383.52","252.00,383.09",
      "244.24,382.57","238.62,383.56","232.21,377.61",
      "228.01,373.71","225.52,365.66","226.13,360.00",
      "226.13,360.00","227.55,354.00","227.55,354.00",
      "228.20,350.96","227.74,347.67","228.74,345.00",
      "230.78,339.55","237.90,331.81","243.00,328.88",
      "248.10,327.42","249.02,328.30","254.00,328.88"
      };
 // The polygons will be stored in instances of Path2D.Float. After we create an instance 
  // of Path2D.Float we must set its vertices -- the easiest way to do this is through the
 // moveTo(x,y) and lineTo(x,y) methods.
 Path2D.Float regionOfInterest = new Path2D.Float();
 // We must store the first X,Y coordinates so we can close the path, by creating a line
 // to the last point to the first one.
 boolean isFirst = true;
 double firstX=0,firstY=0;
 // For each of the X,Y coordinates, parse and store them on the Path2D.Float.    
 for(String s:coordsText)
   {
   String[] xy = s.split(",");
   double x = Double.parseDouble(xy[0]);
   double y = Double.parseDouble(xy[1]);
   if (isFirst) 
     { 
     regionOfInterest.moveTo(x,y); 
     firstX = x;
     firstY = y;
     isFirst = false; 
     }
   else { regionOfInterest.lineTo(x,y); }
   }
 // Close the path.
 regionOfInterest.lineTo(firstX,firstY);
 // We have the path that define the region of interest. In order to dim the image regions
 // outside of this path we must create another path that contains everything but the 
 // region of interest.
 // First we create a path for the whole image -- a rectangle with the image's coordinates.
 Path2D.Float pathForWholeImage = new Path2D.Float();
 pathForWholeImage.moveTo(0,0);
 pathForWholeImage.lineTo(baseImage.getWidth(),0);
 pathForWholeImage.lineTo(baseImage.getWidth(),baseImage.getHeight());
 pathForWholeImage.lineTo(0,baseImage.getHeight());
 pathForWholeImage.lineTo(0,0);
 // In order to use Constructive Area Geometry (CAG) operations we must use the Area class.
 // First we create an Area with the path for the whole image...
 Area wholeImage = new Area(pathForWholeImage);
 // .. then we subtract the region of interest from this Area.
 wholeImage.subtract(new Area(regionOfInterest));
 // Now we have a Path2D.Float for the region of interest and an Area for the rest of the image.    
 // To draw and paint them we need a graphic context, which we will get from the image itself. 
 Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)baseImage.getGraphics();
 // We want antialiasing!
 g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
 // Fill the rest of the image with a transparent (100/255) white.
 g2d.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,100));
 g2d.fill(wholeImage);
 // Draw the region of interest with a thick, almost opaque red line.    
 g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5f));
 g2d.setColor(new Color(255,0,0,200));
 g2d.draw(regionOfInterest);
 // Create a new Frame to show the results.
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 //imageFrame.setTitle("Highlighting image regions");
 // Create an ImageIcon/Label to show the image.
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(baseImage);
 JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
 // Add it to the content pane.
 imageFrame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(label));
// Set some GUI parameters.
 //imageFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
 imageFrame.pack();  
 //frame.setVisible(true); 


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well what you need, this could help:

```
ArrayList<Float> coordsX = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float> coordsY = new ArrayList<Float>();

addMouseMotionListener(this);

this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

        coordsX.add(e.getX()); //Storing coordinate X
        coordsY.add(e.getY()); //Storing coordinate Y

        //Add this code to draw a circle each time you click.
        int r = 6; //Radius of the circle/point.
        int x = e.getX()-(r/2); //Position X (mouse will be in the center of the point)
        int y = e.getY()-(r/2); //Position Y (mouse will be in the center of the point)

        Graphics g = getGraphics(); //Getting the Graphic object
        g.setColor(Color.red); //Setting color to red
        g.fillOval(x, y, r, r); //Drawing the circle/point
        g.dispose();
    }
});
```

Just an example that I think solve what you need, how to store coordinates is up to you.

**UPDATE:** 
In order to draw a point use `fillOval(x, y, r, r)` method from [Graphics class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html).

Btw, if you use `mouseClicked()` event, sometimes you will see how your clicks appear to not have effect (to click doesn't draw or store anything), this is because the program is detecting the `mouseDragged()` event from [MouseMotionListener Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html). To solve this you can change the current event `mouseClicked()` for `mousePressed()` event from [MouseListener Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) as I already did in the code.

If you want a bigger point, just increase its radius, or decrease it if you want it smaller.

Comment: Thank you! Could you also tell me how to mark them as well. As in, marking the location on the image with a red-point or so.